# How to interpolatively fill in a UV map?

Tags: mesh, uv

Say I have a mesh unwrapped, and then because of changes I make to the mesh, a patch in the middle of the UV map gets messed up. The rest of the map is still good. Can I sort of interpolate this middle area from the rest of the UV, that is, UV unwrapping the area with locked outer edges to the area already unwrapped, in a way so that it is actually continuous, and not oddly stretched or broken? So, basically grid fill, but for UVs, and obviously it has to use vertices not make them up?

Comment: Is this post: https://blenderartists.org/t/how-to-make-to-change-uv-synchronously-with-its-mesh/1390115  any help?

Comment: @curious_1 that looks like a similar problem, thank you. I’ll give it a look. Meanwhile, I tried using the smooth UV tool from the Magic UV add-on, because smoothing the map for a particular area is basically what I want to do, but it keeps giving errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can pin UVs in the UV Editor by selecting them and hitting  <kbd>P</kbd> ( <kbd>Alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>P</kbd>  to unpin). If you then unwrap normally( <kbd>U</kbd>  ->  <kbd>U</kbd> ), only the unpinned UVs will move and the operation will attempt to place them correctly in relation with the pined ones.

[image]